# Liquibase rollback, changesets not being rolled back

Tags: sql, command-line, liquibase, rollback, changeset

my problem is that liquibase is not rolling back some of my changesets that have been executed after a tag was set on the change set i am trying to rollback too.

For example I have created two changesets (A and B) which execute as normal. and then i have created another changeset which sets the tag of changeset B to release1. and this changeset also works as expected. however i then execute another 5 changesets all with rollback commands. and these also execute fine.

Now the problem comes when i run the following:

```
java -jar liquibase.jar --changeLogFile=..\database\changelog-create.xml rollback release1
```

Now shouldn't this rollback any changesets that were executed after the release1 tag was executed?

If so, this is my problem, they are not being rolled back. but in console i get Rollback was successful.

Comment: I understand the description of rolling back to a tag ([see here](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/rollback.html)) in the same way. So maybe something else is going wrong. You can try to change the log level to debug (add `--logLevel=debug` to your command line) and see if that gives more details...

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Jens I have tried adding in this debug line but this provides no additional info. i think this only works when there is an exception. im not too sure to be honest but it didn't do anything for me

Comment: You should definitively see a difference in the amount of log messages that liquibase provides. Otherwise the switch for debug log-level did not work!

Comment: @Jens Okay so I got it to display all the debug messages. and it all seems fine, except none of the sql rollbacks seem to be executing. I'm not sure if they are supposed to show up in debug or not, but they aren't doing.Is is possible you could provide a correct way to set a tag please? the current way i am doing it is as follows 'UPDATE DATABASECHANGELOG SET TAG = 'release1' WHERE DATEEXECUTED = (SELECT MAX(DATEEXECUTED) FROM (SELECT DATEEXECUTED FROM DATABASECHANGELOG) AS X) 
      AND ORDEREXECUTED = (SELECT MAX(ORDEREXECUTED) FROM (SELECT ORDEREXECUTED FROM DATABASECHANGELOG) AS Y);'

Comment: Something else i have noticed is that... the only thing being rolled back is the changeset that sets the tag. I would expect this to be rolled back as is was executed 3rd whereas the changelog with tag was executed 2nd. But once again i cant see why the other changesets aren't being rolled back. The other changesets were however executed in a different command afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the problem.. The following line in my command line 
`--changeLogFile=..\database\changelog-create.xml`
Was wrong. The changeLogFile should be the one you want to start the rollback from. Whereas i provided the changelog file with the tag.

Answer (score 0):

For those who will face with similar issues, here is a detailed explanation:

During rollback liquibase compares given parameters with appropriate parameters from a databasechangelog table.

Imagine we are going to invoke a rollback. And we would like to do that outside of a project directory. So, we have the next command:

```
liquibase --url="some-jdbc-url" --changelog-file="/some/path/to/the/db/changelog/changelog-1.json" --username=someusername --password=somepassword rollback-count 1
```

and also we have the next content in our databasechangelog table:

```
|   id  |   author  |       filename               |      dateexecuted     |orderexecuted|exectype|       md5sum                     |  description   |comments|tag|liquibase|contexts|labels|deployment_id|
|-------|-----------|------------------------------|-----------------------|-------------|--------|----------------------------------|----------------|--------|---|---------|--------|------|-------------|
|some-id|some-author|/db/changelog/changelog-1.json|2022-12-29 10:00:00.000|     1       |EXECUTED|8:2645faaa8ad312262c8dc1111eeeeeee|some-description|        |   |  4.18.0 |        |      | 1112233445  |
```

Please note, that a file name in the table is different (e.g. because changelogs were invoked within a project directory during a startup)

So, in this case rollback will not have an effect although `Liquibase command 'rollback-count' was executed successfully` is printed.

**It happens because provided changelog path in the rollback command and a path in the table are not equal**:
(`/some/path/to/the/db/changelog/changelog-1.json` and `/db/changelog/changelog-1.json`).

**They must be equal**

To fix that problem we need to go to the appropriate directory, so our path to the changelog becomes the same. In our example we should go to `/some/path/to/the` and invoke next command:

```
liquibase --url="some-jdbc-url" --changelog-file="/db/changelog/changelog-1.json" --username=someusername --password=somepassword rollback-count 1
```

Now, since `--changelog-file` value and `filename` value are equal, rollback makes changes.

**So, during your investigtions please put attention on parameters matching (between provided in a command and in a databasechangelog table). Check provided changelog path, calculated checksums, authors and so on.**